# SentEvent and Send properties in SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, data

I have data that I am retrieving using SentEvent (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/sentevent.htm) and Send (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/send.htm) objects using SOAP API. I'd like to figure out of these two object have a common property/data point in common so I can match/combine the data in a single view...ideally a batchID/jobID (ID to identify the email/asset that is sent). Is there a way to accomplish this whether its directly through SOAP API retrieval or through comparing the two data sets?

Answer (score 1):

Updating my anwser per Adam’s comment below:

`SentEvent.SendID` = `Send.ID`

---

If I am not mistaken, it should be `SentEvent.SendID` = `Send.ObjectID`.

I like to use the Describe method to get information about the metadata associated with an object, as the documentation isn’t always accurate. You can easily run it on a CloudPage using WSProxy to get all the info you need: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_WSProxy_describe.htm

Depending on what kind of data you are trying to get, there might be easier ways to accomplish this than SOAP API, eg. you can pull 6 months of tracking data from [Data Views](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/08/22/data-views-in-salesforce-marketing-cloud/).

Comment: I believe it's `SentEvent.SendID = Send.ID`

Comment: Thanks @AdamSpriggs, that’s true - I just checked and for the `Send` object, `ID` actually is retrievable, while `ObjectID` is not retrievable.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you have a 'Send' retrieve example using ssjs or know where I can find an example? I haven't been able to find this in documentation.

Comment: See WSProxy retrieve request: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_WSProxy_basic_retrieve.htm or my blog post about retrieving tracking data: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/11/09/retrieve-tracking-data-since-account-inception-using-wsproxy/